# How can i convert 'X' to '*' and them compute it in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

i am building a calculator app although its working fine but i just want to make it look like this before its is been turn into mathematical expression:
how do i achieve something like this:

```
'5X4' = 20
instead of using the asterisk sign '5*4' = 20
```

like i want to be able to replace the string 'X' in background before it's been computed

i tried this code below:

```
final multiply = '5X4';
  final computed = multiply.replaceAll('X','*');
  final result = computed;
```

if i run the

```
print(result)
```

but if i try
`print(int.parse(result));`

the console print out

```
Uncaught Error: FormatException: 5*4
```

how do i fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try this approach.

```
final multiply = '5X4';
  final computed = multiply.replaceAll('X','*');
  final List<String> variable1 = computed.split('*');
  final result = int.parse(variable1.first) * int.parse(variable1.last);
  final lastResult = '$computed = $result';
  
  print(lastResult);
```

[Dartpad](https://dartpad.dev/?)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [expressions](https://pub.dev/packages/expressions) package. Here is an example:

```
String data = "12x2÷3-2+4";
data = data.replaceAll("x", "*");
data = data.replaceAll("÷", "/");

Expression expression = Expression.parse(data);

const evaluator = ExpressionEvaluator();
var r = evaluator.eval(expression, {});
print(r.toString()); // 10.0
```